# jQuery event listeners only work in console

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a strange problem where I define a set of event listeners inside a `document.ready` or a `window.load` and nothing happens when I load the page and try to trigger one of them.

I first thought that it might be a DOM issue, however if I `console.log()` each element I'm binding a listener to, it is logged successfully, indicating to me that it's not a problem with the DOM. If I bind listeners to other elements on my page, those seem to work fine. If I simply copy/paste the code below into the console, everything works fine.

I've also tried not wrapping them in a `document.ready` or `window.load` function, but that makes no difference. I've tried adjusting the location of the script. I've placed it in the head, the footer, and in a separate file to be loaded through the asset pipeline in Rails. Again, it makes no difference.

There are no other listeners tied to these elements anywhere in my code. What am I missing here?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // This console.log() statement returns the correct DOM element
    console.log($('#direct-apply-btn'));

    // As does this one:
    console.log($('[data-toggle="popover-filter"]'));

    var popoverTextFilter = "Some text here.";
    var popoverTextButton = "Some other text here.";

    $('[data-toggle="popover-filter"]').popover({
        delay: {show: "500", hide: "100"},
        content: popoverTextFilter,
        trigger: "hover",
        placement: "top"
    });

    $('[data-toggle="popover-btn"]').popover({
        delay: {show: "500", hide: "100"},
        content: popoverTextButton,
        trigger: "hover",
        placement: "top"
    });

    if(location.hash.includes('direct_apply')) {
        $('.direct-apply-filter').addClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
        $('.direct-apply-text').addClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
    }

    $('#direct-apply-btn').click(function() {
        $('.direct-apply-filter').toggleClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
        $('.direct-apply-text').toggleClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
    });

    $('.clear-filters-btn').click(function(){
        $('.direct-apply-filter').removeClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
        $('.direct-apply-text').removeClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
    });
    // This listener works fine.    
    $('.header').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background','red');
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

I came up with a hack that gets the event listeners to trigger. It's a little buggy, but it's better than nothing. See code below. I'm still really hoping to find out why `$(document).ready` or `$(window).load` wouldn't work for me. The code below seems to trigger all the event listeners, but it's not a long-term solution for my app and it doesn't work on mobile.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    directApplyEventListeners();
});

function directApplyEventListeners() {
    var popoverTextFilter = "Some text here.";
    var popoverTextButton = "Some other text here.";

    dataToggles();

    $('.search-results').bindWithDelay('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
        dataToggles();
    });

    function dataToggles() {
        $('[data-toggle="popover-filter"]').popover({
            delay: {show: "500", hide: "100"},
            content: popoverTextFilter,
            trigger: "hover",
            placement: "top"
        });

        $('[data-toggle="popover-btn"]').popover({
            delay: {show: "500", hide: "100"},
            content: popoverTextButton,
            trigger: "hover",
            placement: "top"
        });
    };

    if(location.hash.includes('direct_apply')) {
        $('.direct-apply-filter').addClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
        $('.direct-apply-text').addClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
    }

    $('#direct-apply-btn').click(function() {
        $('.direct-apply-filter').toggleClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
        $('.direct-apply-text').toggleClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
    });

    $('.clear-filters-btn').click(function(){
        $('.direct-apply-filter').removeClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
        $('.direct-apply-text').removeClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
    });
};
```

**UPDATE 2**
Here is the rendered portion of the DOM that the event listeners should be bound to:

```
<div class="filters ng-scope full-dna-search" ng-class="{'full-dna-search':fullDnaSearch}" ng-controller="FiltersCtrl">
    <div class="filter-container r1">
        <div class="filter-label basic-search">Basic Search</div>

        <div class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope" dropdown="" name="cityDropdown.name" items="cityDropdown.items" category="cityDropdown.category">
            <div class="filter-button" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
                <span class="text ng-binding">City</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="dd_arrow filter ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible"></div>
            <div class="dropdown-directive-menu ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible">
                <a class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearAllItems(); $event.stopPropagation();"><span ng-show="hasFilteredItems" class="ng-hide">Clear all</span></a>
                <form name="dropdown_form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope" dropdown="" name="industryDropdown.name" items="industryDropdown.items" category="industryDropdown.category">
            <div class="filter-button" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
                <span class="text ng-binding">Industry</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="dd_arrow filter ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible"></div>
            <div class="dropdown-directive-menu ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible">
                <a class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearAllItems(); $event.stopPropagation();"><span ng-show="hasFilteredItems" class="ng-hide">Clear all</span></a>
                <form name="dropdown_form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Financial</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Marketing</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Technology</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope" dropdown="" name="sizeDropdown.name" items="sizeDropdown.items" category="sizeDropdown.category">
            <div class="filter-button" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
                <span class="text ng-binding">Size</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="dd_arrow filter ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible"></div>
            <div class="dropdown-directive-menu ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible">
                <a class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearAllItems(); $event.stopPropagation();"><span ng-show="hasFilteredItems" class="ng-hide">Clear all</span></a>
                <form name="dropdown_form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">1-10 Employees</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope" dropdown="" name="jfuncDropdown.name" items="jfuncDropdown.items" category="jfuncDropdown.category">
            <div class="filter-button" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
                <span class="text ng-binding">Job Function</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="dd_arrow filter ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible"></div>
            <div class="dropdown-directive-menu ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible">
                <a class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearAllItems(); $event.stopPropagation();"><span ng-show="hasFilteredItems" class="ng-hide">Clear all</span></a>
                <form name="dropdown_form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Customer Support</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Engineering</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">IT</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Management</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Marketing</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Sales</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Tech Support</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope ng-hide" dropdown="" name="experienceDropdown.name" items="experienceDropdown.items" category="experienceDropdown.category" ng-hide="true">
            <div class="filter-button" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
                <span class="text ng-binding">Experience Level</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="dd_arrow filter ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible"></div>
            <div class="dropdown-directive-menu ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible">
                <a class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearAllItems(); $event.stopPropagation();"><span ng-show="hasFilteredItems" class="ng-hide">Clear all</span></a>
                <form name="dropdown_form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Internship</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Entry Level</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Mid Level</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Senior Level</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                        <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <span class="text ng-binding">Manager</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope" data-toggle="popover-filter" filterbutton="" name="directApplyButton.name" data-original-title="" title="">
            <div id="direct-apply-btn" class="filter-button" ng-click="showDirectApply = !showDirectApply; toggleFilter(showDirectApply); $event.stopPropagation();">
                <div class="direct-apply-filter"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                <span class="direct-apply-text text ng-binding">DirectApply<span class="tm">TM</span></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right-buttons">
            <div class="filter-button-container">
                <div class="filter-button ng-hide" ng-show="filtersApplied || !signedIn" ng-click="openSaveSearchConf()">
                    Save this search
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="filter-button-container">
                <div class="filter-button" ng-show="savedSearches.length > 0" ng-click="openSavedSearches()" style="">
                    My saved searches
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="filter-label workplace-dna">Workplace<span class="itlc">DNA</span><span class="tm">TM</span></div>

    <div class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope" dropdown="" name="workStyleDropdown.name" items="workStyleDropdown.items" category="workStyleDropdown.category">
        <div class="filter-button" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
            <span class="text ng-binding">Work Style</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="dd_arrow filter ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-directive-menu ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible">
            <a class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearAllItems(); $event.stopPropagation();"><span ng-show="hasFilteredItems" class="ng-hide">Clear all</span></a>
            <form name="dropdown_form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="text ng-binding">Cooperative &amp; Collaborative</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="text ng-binding">Competitive &amp; Risk-Taking</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope" dropdown="" name="paceDropdown.name" items="paceDropdown.items" category="paceDropdown.category">
        <div class="filter-button" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
            <span class="text ng-binding">Pace</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="dd_arrow filter ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-directive-menu ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible">
            <a class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearAllItems(); $event.stopPropagation();"><span ng-show="hasFilteredItems" class="ng-hide">Clear all</span></a>
            <form name="dropdown_form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="text ng-binding">Steady &amp; Predictable</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="text ng-binding">Fast &amp; Unpredictable</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope" dropdown="" name="feedbackMentoringDropdown.name" items="feedbackMentoringDropdown.items" category="feedbackMentoringDropdown.category">
        <div class="filter-button" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
            <span class="text ng-binding">Feedback &amp; Mentoring</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="dd_arrow filter ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-directive-menu ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible">
            <a class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearAllItems(); $event.stopPropagation();"><span ng-show="hasFilteredItems" class="ng-hide">Clear all</span></a>
            <form name="dropdown_form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="text ng-binding">Informal &amp; On-the-Fly</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="text ng-binding">Structured &amp; Regular</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope" dropdown="" name="dressCodeDropdown.name" items="dressCodeDropdown.items" category="dressCodeDropdown.category">
        <div class="filter-button" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
            <span class="text ng-binding">Dress Code</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="dd_arrow filter ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-directive-menu ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible">
            <a class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearAllItems(); $event.stopPropagation();"><span ng-show="hasFilteredItems" class="ng-hide">Clear all</span></a>
            <form name="dropdown_form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="text ng-binding">Business Formal</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="text ng-binding">Business Casual</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="text ng-binding">Casual</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope" dropdown="" name="eventsActivitiesDropdown.name" items="eventsActivitiesDropdown.items" category="eventsActivitiesDropdown.category">
        <div class="filter-button" ng-click="toggleMenu()">
            <span class="text ng-binding">Events &amp; Activities</span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="dd_arrow filter ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-directive-menu ng-hide" ng-show="menuVisible">
            <a class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearAllItems(); $event.stopPropagation();"><span ng-show="hasFilteredItems" class="ng-hide">Clear all</span></a>
            <form name="dropdown_form" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="text ng-binding">Every Now &amp; Then</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="i in items" class="ng-scope">
                    <div class="filter-item" ng-class="{selected: i.selected}" ng-click="toggleItem($index); $event.stopPropagation();">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="i.selected" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="text ng-binding">Frequent</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="right-buttons filter-right-buttons">
        <a class="clear-filters-btn ng-hide" ng-show="filtersApplied" ng-click="clearAllFilters()">Clear filters</a>
        <a class="expand-filters-btn" ng-click="expandFilters()" ng-show="!expanded">All filters <i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding to the issue, your problem is with Javscript comments.

Javascript comments doesn't start with "#" rather starts with "//" for single line comment and /**/ for multiline comments.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // This console.log() statement returns the correct DOM element
    console.log($('#direct-apply-btn'));

    // As does this one:
    console.log($('[data-toggle="popover-filter"]'));

    var popoverTextFilter = "Some text here.";
    var popoverTextButton = "Some other text here.";

    $('[data-toggle="popover-filter"]').popover({
        delay: {show: "500", hide: "100"},
        content: popoverTextFilter,
        trigger: "hover",
        placement: "top"
    });

    $('[data-toggle="popover-btn"]').popover({
        delay: {show: "500", hide: "100"},
        content: popoverTextButton,
        trigger: "hover",
        placement: "top"
    });

    if(location.hash.includes('direct_apply')) {
        $('.direct-apply-filter').addClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
        $('.direct-apply-text').addClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
    }

    $('#direct-apply-btn').click(function() {
        $('.direct-apply-filter').toggleClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
        $('.direct-apply-text').toggleClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
    });

    $('.clear-filters-btn').click(function(){
        $('.direct-apply-filter').removeClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
        $('.direct-apply-text').removeClass('direct-apply-btn-active');
    });

    $('.header').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background','red');
    });
});
```

Comment: I just put those comments in there when I was writing the post. They aren't in my actual code. Thanks for catching that though.

Comment: look at this fiddle. console logs are working http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/amur2abs/